# Google Tag Manager: Tracking "Select" Drop Down Menu "Option" tag value

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-handling, google-tag-manager, dom-events

I am having trouble tracking the value of the "option" tag in the "select" tag.
I currently have a drop down menu for Google Translator Widget where user can click on it and select the language.
When you click on the "Select Language" drop down, you will be able to see German as the option.
See the attached screenshots. 
I have created a Macro call "JS - Google Translate - Select Option" in the Google Tag Manager.

Here is the code for "JS - Google Translate - Select Option":

```js
function() {
  var list = document.querySelector('select.goog-te-combo');
  return list ? list.options[list.selectedIndex].value : undefined;
}
```

Above code, will find the drop down menu, which has "goog-te-combo" as a class name for "select" tag. Then, it will see if the option tags are available in the select tag and get the value of the selected option tag.

I also have created a tag call "GA - Event - Google Translate Clicks" and trigger call "Click - Google Translate".

When I test this out, I see that my "GA - Event - Google Translate Clicks" get triggered when I click on the drop down menu on my page.
However, when I check the "variables" tab in the Google Tag Manager and check the variable "JS - Google Translate - Select Option", I see it empty.

[Google Translator Widget Drop down menu option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICWSl.png)

[Google Tag Manager "JS - Google Translate - Select Option" empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sllz2.png)

Comment: Can you please add information how did you define "Click - Google Translate"? I guess your goal is to fire tag, when someone translated the page. Right?

Comment: @VictorLeontyev For "Click - Google Translate", I chose "Click - All Elements" for "Trigger Type", "Some Clicks" for "This trigger fires on",  and "Click Element, matches CSS selector, select.goog-te-combo" for "Fire this trigger when an event occurs and all of these conditions are true".

Yes, that is right, my goal is to fire tag when someone translated the page.

Comment: See the article https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-selection-drop-list/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is that you need to trigger tag when `onchange` event happens.

**Full guide how to track page translations, if you are using Google Website translator**

First of all you need to set up custom event trigger for `onchange` event  (original article about that you can find [here](https://medium.com/archergroup/custom-event-trigger-set-up-in-google-tag-manager-gtm-v3-d7c243258065)):

**Setup custom event listener**

Go to Triggers-> New -> Custom Event

- Event name: gtm.js
- Trigger name: gtm.js

**Setup event handler JS variable**

Go to Variable -> User-Defined variables -> New -> Type -> Custom JavaScript

```
function() {
    return function(e) {
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'gtm.'+e.type,
            'gtm.element': e.target,
            'gtm.elementClasses': e.target.className || '',
            'gtm.elementId': e.target.id || '',
            'gtm.elementTarget': e.target.target || '',
            'gtm.elementUrl': e.target.href || e.target.action || '',
            'gtm.originalEvent': e
        });
    }
}
```

Variable name: generic event handler

**Setup tag**

Go to Tags-> New -> Type -> Custom HTML

HTML:

```
<script>
    var eventType = 'change'; // Modify this to reflect the event type you want to listen for
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener(eventType, {{generic event handler}}, false);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent('on' + eventType, {{generic event handler}});
    }
</script>
```

Tag name: onchange listener

Trigger: gtm.js

---

Now, you created everything what you need for tracking `onchange` events. Next steps is for exact your case, when you want to fire tag when someone translated the page

**Enable built-in variable for Click element**

Go to Variables-> Built-In variables-> Configure -> Click Element

**Create variable for selected language**

Go to Variables-> User-Defined variables -> New-> Custom JavaScript

```
function() {
    var list = document.querySelector('select.goog-te-combo');
    return list ? list.options[list.selectedIndex].value : undefined;
}
```

Variable name: Selected language

**Create trigger for your tag**

Go to Triggers -> New -> Type -> Custom Event

Event type: gtm.change

Fires on: Some Custom Events

`Click Element` - `Matches CSS selector` - `select.goog-te-combo`

Trigger name: Page translated

**Create final tag, which will fire event, when someone translated the page**

This step might be different. It depends, what tag type do you want to fire. In this example i will send event to GA

Go to Tags-> New -> Type -> Universal Analytics

Type: Event

Category: Translate

Action: Translate

Label: {{Selected language}}

Trigger: Page translated

**DONE**

After this steps you will have working solution

Comment: When I'm only implementing 1 of these, I prefer to define the event handler function in the custom HTML tag itself instead of splitting them up

Answer (score 1):

I believe what may be happening is that your trigger is firing **before** the variable has had time to evaluate.

A neater way to do this would be to define to use the `onchange` handler of the `<select>` tag to push an event onto the GTM dataLayer along with the value that was selected. This may look something like this:

```
<select id="language" onChange="languageSelected(this.selectedIndex);>
```

Your `languageSelected` function might look something like this:

```
function languageSelected(index) {
   dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
   dataLayer.push({'event' : 'languageSelected', 'language' : 'German'});
}
```

You would then define a dataLayer variable in GTM that reads the `language` attribute from the dataLayer and then you would define a trigger of type Custom Event where the event name is `languageSelected`.

Comment: This would only work if you have access to the underlying HTML, which is not needed for the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

It's working perfectly fine but `gtm.change` dropdown class `select.goog-te-combo` fired in 3 times.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question