# Google Tag Manager, track qmbo Box changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tag-manager

We are trying to track what qmbo box changes are done by Google Tag Manager but Click Text is always showing the same. 
Is there any known way to get the current selected value selected ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you read [Google Tag Manager: Tracking “Select” Drop Down Menu “Option” tag value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45246152/1330560). Though it refers to Translate, the issue appears to be similar.  [#GTMTips: Track Selection In Drop-Down List](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-selection-drop-list/) on www.simoahava.com also seems relevant, though I'm not expert in Tag Manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Tag Manager: Tracking "Select" Drop Down Menu "Option" tag value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246152/google-tag-manager-tracking-select-drop-down-menu-option-tag-value)